# Getting error about api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll

Tags: c++, qt, dll, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 project. My Visual Studio 2015 has update 2. When I run program I get error.

> The procedure entry point GetLastError could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 is installed. And now it is uninstalled and reinstalled.
Copying api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll to program directory doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Getting these minwin forwarder dlls corrupted by a crappy installer is an ugly problem.  The correct answer depends on your Windows version.  But in general either deleting the DLL from the c:\windows\system32 and c:\windows\syswow64 directories or restoring them from a known-good machine is the approach.  You should have a good copy in your C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs directory btw.

Comment: this file is part of Windows, so run DISM to repair them: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/joscon/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012/